# django: how can i make a generic list view see a regular model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Sorry if this is a dumb way to ask this...
I have a generic list view for the homepage of a site, and would like to use a "homepage" model for informative text on that same page...is it possible? Thanks for your help.

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models


class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Maximum 250 characters.')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.school_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/schools/%s/" % self.slug

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Maximum 250 characters.')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    mugshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='mugshots')
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)  
    honor = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/student/%s/" % self.slug

class Homepage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Maximum 250 characters.')
    content = models.TextField() 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from achievers.apps.students.models import School, Student
from achievers.apps.students.views import hello

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

info_dict = {
    'queryset': School.objects.all(),
    'extra_context': {'school_list': School.objects.all,}    
}

info_dict2 = {
    'queryset': Student.objects.all(),
    'template_name': 'students/student_detail.html',
    'extra_context': {'student_detail': Student.objects.all}    
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'static'}),
    (r'^student/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict2), 
    (r'^students/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', info_dict),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^hello/', hello),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you would like to "use" the homepage model with the generic list view. If you simply want access to all instances of `Homepage`, you can add the following to info_dict in your urls.py:

```
info_dict = {
    'queryset' : School.objects.all(),
    'extra_context' : {'school_list' : School.objects.all(), 'homepage_list' : Homepage.objects.all()}
}
```

You can use a similar technique if you want to pass a specific instance of `Homepage` to the generic view:

```
...
'extra_context' : {'school_list' : School.objects.all(), 'homepage' : Homepage.objects.filter(id = 1).get()}
```

Finally, if you want something more complex (like a dynamic `id` to be used on the filter), you can always define a custom view, and then call `object_list` from within that view, like:

```
def my_view(request, dynamic_id):
    info_dict = {..., 'extra_context' : {..., 'homepage' : Homepage.objects.filter(id = dynamic_id).get()}}
    return django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list(**info_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I was making it harder than it needed to be. Your first suggestion worked perfectly, and I'll keep the others for when I need to do something more advanced. Thanks again.